# PHP returns 0 after a multiplication operation

Tags: php, integer

I need to temporarily store the value in a PHP variable because the value should be sent together with a comment. A user cannot send a rating without entering a comment, that's why I decided to make this.

Why is that when PHP calculates the value my variable returns a value of zero?

I have this code:

`<a href='#' onclick='rate(1); return false;' class='one-star'>1</a>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function rate (amnt){
     <?php
         $currentRating = amnt;
         $ratingImageWidth = $currentRating * 25;
         echo "alert($ratingImageWidth)";
     ?>
     }
</script>
```

Note:

It outputs an alert with 0;

`$currentRating` variable is not null, I tried to include it in the alert function, and it returns the right value.

I tried these to convert the `$currentRating` variable to an int:

`settype($currentRating, "integer");`

`(int)$currentRating;`

Nothing happened, it still returns Zero. does anyone know how to solve this? Big thanks to those who will help.

Comment: PHP runs on the server, JavaScript at the client. You cannot mix them in this way.

Comment: How will I make this calculation possible?

Comment: You can't mix both JS and PHP , furthermore , there's a } tag missing in the end of the functions (altough it won't solve your problem)

Comment: Just do it all with JavaScript: `function rate(amnt) { alert(parseInt(amnt) * 25); }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP runs on the server, so your JavaScript actually looks like:

```
function rate(amnt) {
    alert(0)
```

It's surprising that it works at all given the missing `}` at the end...

The point is, you can't mix PHP and JS in this way. Why don't you just do `alert(amnt*25)`?

Comment: I cannot do the `alert(amnt*25)`, in my case, I need to store it in a PHP variable to check if a user rated before entering a comment and submit it to the database.

Comment: In that case, you need to use AJAX to send the call to the server, and use the response to show the result.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you trying to use PHP for this? Just do the calculation in javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function rate (amnt){
         var ratingImageWidth = amnt * 25;
         alert(ratingImageWidth);
     }
</script>
```

PHP runs on the server before the browser loads the page. Javascript runs in the client's browser after the page is loaded. The two can't call each other, because they're running in different places.

Comment: I need to store it in a php variable because it should be a global one. I want to check if a user rated before a comment is sent, and it is the only solution that I have thought.

Comment: Then you're going to need to use AJAX to send a request to the server.

Answer (score 2):

Php code run before it is sent to the user. Try to view the source of your processed page to understand how it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ php << EOF
<?php
echo amnt * 25;
EOF
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant amnt - assumed 'amnt' in - on line 2

Notice: Use of undefined constant amnt - assumed 'amnt' in - on line 2
0
```

**You can't run PHP from JavaScript like this.** Use XHR instead, or stick to JavaScript